# Arduino: issue including ShiftPWM library in custom library

Tags: arduino, libraries

I recently came across [ShiftPWM](http://www.elcojacobs.com/shiftpwm/), which is optimized to control RGB LEDs using shift registers.

I downloaded the source code and was able to run the example provided on my breadboard no problem. I even tweaked the sketch a bit and feel comfortable using the functions in the ShiftPWM library.

I would like to include the ShiftPWM functionality in a current project I'm working on, which already has a ton of library files. I'd like to `#include "ShiftPWM.h` into my `Registers.h` file, so that I can use my own syntax and object-oriented hierarchy to light up my LEDs.

In the example arduino sketch, I need to define a few constants before including the ShiftPWM library file:

```
#define SHIFTPWM_NOSPI
const int ShiftPWM_latchPin = 2;
const int ShiftPWM_dataPin  = 4;
const int ShiftPWM_clockPin = 3;
const bool ShiftPWM_invertOutputs = true;
const bool ShiftPWM_balanceLoad = false;
#include "ShiftPWM.h"
```

So I figured I could simply copy these lines into my `Registers.h` file, as well as the setup code and other functions that go about lighting up the LEDs.

But, when I do this and try to compile my arduino sketch, which only includes `Registers.h`, my compiler gives me the following (abbreviated) errors:

```
multiple definitions of '__vector_11'
.../ShiftPWM/ShiftPWM.h:175 first defined here
multiple definitions of 'ShiftPWM'
.../ShiftPWM/ShiftPWM.h:175 first defined here
```

The line it is referring to is this:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    ShiftPWM_handleInterrupt();
}
```

My research indicates this line of code has something to do with the timers used by the arduino to run interrupts. People often get the 'multiple definitions of __vector_11' error when they try to run the arduino Servo and Tone library, for instance, because they both attempt to use timer1.

I am wondering why I am getting this error simply by attempting to link to the ShiftPWM library from my own custom library. Nowhere in my code do I manually set any sort of timer. I am assuming it stems from some linking issue, but I really can't figure out what that may be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest code from the [github repository](https://github.com/elcojacobs/ShiftPWM)?

Comment: yes, I downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: The download link on the ShiftPWM page goes to a version from last year. https://github.com/elcojacobs/ShiftPWM/archive/master.zip should get you the latest version from github. It looks like some compatibility fixes were made since then. It may not fix the problem and may be broken in other ways but it is a place to start.